# Blocking on Input in Java

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I'm new to Java so I apologize for what is probably a very naive question.  I'm writing an application that will communicate with several other processes.  The latter will read and write from stdin and stdout.  I'd like to redirect their input and output to process-specific files and read and write from there.

I seem to be having trouble with the reading part.  In particular, if the data hasn't already appeared in the input file then InputStream.read() seems to be returning -1 rather than waiting for it.  I've searched a bit for the solution and everything I've found seems to indicate that the problem is with closing the stream prematurely.  I don't think I'm doing that though.

Here's some snippets of relevant code:

```
class Player {
    public Player(String Infile, String Outfile, int initBankRoll) {
           File inFile;
           File outFile;

           try {
               reader = new FileInputStream(Infile);
           }
           catch (IOException ioe) {
               System.err.println("Could not open " + Infile);  
               }
    ...
    }

    public String readln() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(80);
       int i;
       try {
          while ( (i = reader.read()) != '\n') {
         sb.append(i);
          }
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
          System.err.println("Could not read from file.");  
       }
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

For what it's worth, I'd rather have a quick solution than an elegant one.  Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Oh -- this may be relevant.  I'm trying to test sending the input by typing
       cat - > TESTFILE
on a terminal...

Comment: Transfering data through TCP can be a good solution for communating between applications

Comment: Thanks for that MJafar -- I thought about that and it might be the better approach.  I'm sort of going for quick and dirty at this point though :)

Comment: I changed my code to just loop while getting -1:
 while ( (i = reader.read()) == -1);
     sb.append( (char) i);
     while ( (i = reader.read()) != '\n') {
  System.err.println("Got:  " + ( (char) i));
  sb.append((char) i);
     }

This seems to work but seems like a terrible waste of machine cycles...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know i understand your question properly, but basically you want read lines from file and if there is no other line, you want wait for it? Right?

If so, this might be solution:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Player player  = new Player("C:\\Data\\test.txt");
    while(true) {//do whatever condition you want here
        System.out.println("Write:");
        String line = player.readln();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
public class Player {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    public Player(String fileName) {
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Could not open " + fileName);
        }
    }

    public String readln() {
        String line = null;
        try {
            while(true){ //this will wait till new line in file
                if((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
                    return line;
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Could not read from file.");
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```